# c++ struct, how to create struct objects dynamically,

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
struct MYSTRUCT {
    ....
};
```

if I create struct objects with a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    MYSTRUCT *mystruct;
}
```

will `mystruct` be the same every time because of the same name? What's the difference between the code above and this code:

```
MYSTRUCT *mystruct0;
MYSTRUCT *mystruct1;
```

How can I create different struct objects in a simpler way?

```
MYSTRUCT *mystruct0;
MYSTRUCT *mystruct1;
...
MYSTRUCT *mystruct99;
MYSTRUCT *mystruct100;
```

If I do the way below, will all the struct pointers same or they are isolated from each other?

```
vector<MYSTRUCT *> mystructs;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    MYSTRUCT *mystruct;
    mystructs.push_back();
}
```

Comment: Your looking for the concept of "Array".

Comment: Take a step back. Do you need to use pointers to the structs at all? Why are you doing what you are doing?

Comment: I do not think a pointer is what you want. If you were newing that memory yes every one would be unique the name does not matter. Though JBL is right what you are looking for is called a Array. Or a list/vector.

Comment: @JBL Well, a collection of some sort.

Comment: BTW, you are not creating structures in either example. You are creating uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and don't worry about it.

Comment: `MYSTRUCT* mystruct;` is not creating an object, it declares a pointer. Why do you want to do it dynamically?

Comment: sorry, I meant: why do you want to take care of dynamic memory allocation by yourself? Let someone else do the dirty work for you (e.g. std::vector)

Comment: Also the pointer inside the for loop will no longer exist outside the scope of the for loop and it is only 1 pointer not 2.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you should never try to generate variable names.
it's just not the way to do it.

You should use a container (like in your example a `std::vector`) which is exactly what you want : something to put several other things of the same type.

In your example :

```
struct MyStruct {  // Don't name your struct in all caps.
                   // it's generally reserved for MACROS. Use CamelCase
    // blablabla

}
```

Do not use pointers unless you need to, usually it is much easier **and** much more efficient to use values. If you need to pass one of the elements of your vector to a function, so this function can modify it, you can pass an iterator to that element.

```
vector<MyStruct> mystructs;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    mystructs.emplace_back(MyStruct{});
}
```

Also if your struct has fields that need to be initialized, you might want to use an initializer list or define a constructor.

If you need to use dynamic allocation you can do something like this :

```
vector<MyStruct*> mystructs;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    mystructs.emplace_back(new MyStruct{});
}
```

Now the vector contains the pointers, not the objects. Each object is allocated individually in his own memory emplacement, therefore there is no garantee that they are next to each other.
This matters tremendously for performance : Pointers give you indirection.
Indirection leads to pain. Pain leads to anger ... blablabla => Welcome to the dark side.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    MYSTRUCT *mystruct;
}
```

You're not creating objects at all. All you're doing is *declaring* pointers to `MYSTRUCT`. These pointers are uninitialized and therefore don't point to anything (yet). Moreover, the pointer (`mystruct`) itself is allocated on the stack and has a lifetime limited to the scope of your for-loop.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you need multiple objects of type `MYSTRUCT`, you should not try to create them in a loop like that. Rather, declare an array or `std::vector` and initialize appropriately. I will leave it to you to figure out how to do this. When you do, be aware of the difference between static and dynamic arrays, and their consequences for memory management!

**EDIT:**
On request, I'll elaborate on the final snippet you provided:

```
vector<MYSTRUCT *> mystructs;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    MYSTRUCT *mystruct;
    mystructs.push_back();
}
```

What happens here is you declare an empty vector of pointers to `MYSTRUCT`. So far so good. Now, judging on the body, you want to populate this vector with pointers to actual objects, but this is not happening in your code. I doubt this will even compile, given that `push_back` requires a `MYSTRUCT*` as an argument. Therefore, to do what you intend to do, your code should in each iteration:

1. Allocate an object **on the heap**.
2. Push a pointer to this object to the back of the vector.

This would look like the following:

```
vector<MYSTRUCT*> vec;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) // pre-incr is good practice!
    vec.push_back(new MYSTRUCT); // optionally add constructor arguments
```

However, this introduces you to new responsibilities: you are the one requesting the memory explicitly using `new`, so you should free the memory explicitly using `delete`. Unless `MYSTRUCT` is polymorphic (contains virtual members), you can easily circumvent this (even it it *is* polymorphic, you shouldn't do this, but that's another topic).

The answer to this problem is: don't store pointers, store objects:

```
vector<MYSTRUCT> vec; // no pointer!
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    vec.push_back(MYSTRUCT()); // create an unnamed instance and copy to the back of the vec
```

There, you have just created a vector of `n` MYSTRUCT instances. No pointers, no `new` and `delete`, simple and easy!

Comment: could you explain a little bit my last question?

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` is a datatype that you defined, when you do `MYSTRUCT *mystruct` you declare a *pointer* to a `MYSTRUCT` object and the pointer is called `mystruct` It is the same thing you do with `int *pointer_to_int`.

For you first version, you redeclare `mystruct` at each iteration while your second declares two independant variables. If you want to declare a set of `MYSTRUCT*` easily, use an array of `MYSTRUCT*`: `MYSTRUCT* mystruct_pointers_array[100]`.

*NOTE* `MYSTRUCT*` pointers are different than `MYSTRUCT` variables, you need to dereference the pointer to access to `MYSTRUCT` elements. E.g. `mystruct->x`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a std::vector for this purpose:

```
std::vector<MYSTRUCT *> v(100);
for (auto& pointer : v)
   pointer = new MYSTRUCT(/*...*/); //initializating (writing address to pointer)
```

In your way you just initializing a object of pointer type. In other words you allocating memory only for pointer, where you must write address to your structure or **nullptr**-value.

Comment: I think it's dangerous to point an obvious novice (no disrespect intended) towards allocating objects on the heap using new and storing these pointers in a vector. A better alternative would be to store the objects directly in a vector and let that worry about resource management instead.

Comment: Your example won't compile if you declare `pointer` as a `const` reference.

Comment: @JorenHeit
I am rather a novice too. I'll keep in mind it, thanks.

But what if we'll use the vector of unique_ptr-s && make_unique in this case?

Comment: @François Moisan
fixed, i get used to it.

Comment: You should at least mention deleting all elements. Moreover, there's really no need for storing pointers (unless OP wants to use polymorphism, but I doubt it), as `vector` already dynamically allocates it's elements. Having this, `std::vector::reserve()` and `std::vector::emplace_back` I don't see any need for using `new` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Others have said similar things to this, but specifically I'd do it like this:

```
std::vector <MYSTRUCT *> vect;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    vect.push_back();
}
```

Then you can just access each element like an array, like `vect[0]`. Plus with `std::vector` you can access the first element (element 0) with `vect.front()` and the last with `vect.back()`.

Though it's useless without assigning a `MYSTRUCT` that has been initialized separately, I can see the usefulness of `struct *` vectors.

Comment: this doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: First of all, It won't compile (empty `push_back()`). Secondly, even if it would (and used default constructor), then why not just initialize `vector` with default elements? Lastly, you didn't mention need of using `new` and `delete` nor proposed smart pointers or not using any pointers at all.

Comment: Riiight, I had an idiot moment with regards to `push_back()`. I assumed the number of elements in the vector would need to be chosen after it was initialized, although using default elements would make more sense otherwise. How would you avoid using pointers when storing a reference to an object?

Comment: @zoska Ok, you're right, it doesn't make any sense. I realize now that if storing references to objects, you'd assign the pointers individually, not in a `for` loop. Which is likely not what they wanted to do.